# In what circumstances support of transaction is not that important?

Tags: database, transactions, nosql, rdbms

After posting the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729779/why-nosql-is-better-at-scaling-out-than-rdbms/8729888#8729888), I got to know that NoSQL are better at scaling out because they make a trade off between support for transaction and scalability.

So I wonder in what circumstances transactions are not that important so that scalability is more preferable to support of transaction?

Comment: Well RavendDB does support [transactions](http://ravendb.net/faq/working-with-dtc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would say first that NoSQL is better at scaling is some situations, but not all.

Full ACID transactions are Atomic, Consistent, Isolated and Durable.  If you lose transactions, you will loose some or all of ACID within the datastore.

There are many ways to restore these functions with other asynchronous systems like message queues that themselves are durable.  You can shove data onto a durable message queue, pop the data and deal with it in your NoSQL, then, when you can confirm it's stored to your required minimum, you can flag the message as consumed.  It's the D in ACID, but distributed and asynchronous.  There are ways to ensure the others, but they are often sacrificed to some extent, or moved into another place in the system.  With some NoSQL solutions, you just have to move consistency into the application so it doesn't try to store invalid data.

When you start moving away from database driven transactions, you must increase your application testing dramatically to ensure your system doesn't fail (for some values of fail).

There are essentially no situations where transactions and constraints are not important in a system that has both read and write requirements.  If they weren't you wouldn't care about your data at all (and some people don't, but regret it later).  There are however levels of "caring".  It's just a matter of how you end up at ACID or some pseudo-ACID that's "good enough".  RDMBS makes caring about your data cheap.  NoSQL makes caring about your data expensive, but, it makes scaling cheap(er) (in some cases).  There are many companies with multi-terabyte database in RDBMSes, so to say unilaterally that "they don't scale" is simply inaccurate.  Multi-terabyte SQL databases however, can cost lots of money, depending on the use case (you can after all just slap a RAID 10 array with a few 3TB drives onto a computer and throw a database engine on it.  Might take several minutes to a few hours to do any kind of table scan on a big table, or even indexed look-up though, but if you don't care, it's cheap and multi-terabyte).

Answer (score 0):

The biggest category is read-only type queries, where an aborted or botched transaction can simply be repeated.  Anything where you are changing an underlying state, or want to guarantee once and only once activity, should have proper transactional semantics.

That is, "I want to order one widget, charge my credit card" should be a proper transaction: I don't want my card charged unless the widget is ordered, and the vendor doesn't want the widget sent unless the card is charged.  "Report the shipment status of order xyz" doesn't need to be transactional -- if I don't get an answer, I can hit reload.

Comment: It's not botched or aborted transactions that are the problem in read-only queries.  The problem comes when you need to read multiple pieces of information in a single transaction, and some other transaction changes the data in the meantime.  You end up reading data from one place that says A, but then the next read you do ends up with B, giving conflicting information back to the application.  This situation is why I avoid SQL Server because using snapshot isolation is a pain, and read committed can cause really bad locking problems with long running transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Much of it is just a bit of lateral thinking.
Thw whole point of transcation is you wrap up several operations, and should any fail all that have succeeded get rolled back, and while the transaction is in progress, records are locked and unless you have read uncommitted going, you don't see any on the individual changes of state until the transaction is committed.

Doing all that with distributed systems is expensive, because you need one 'central' and difficult to scale point that needs to 'know' all about the others.

So instead or Order this, charge my card, and show me my current balance.

You do Try to order this, if it's instock charge my card, and if my card gets charged the current known balance will be this.
There's a risk, that the order will be placed, put payment fail, so you need to deal with that. There's a risk that the proposed balance of the card my not be entirely accurate, hence add weasel words and show the potential effect of payment as opposed to the result.

It's not so much are transactions important, it's seeing as they aren't as well supported in NoSQL systems, where/how can I get away with not using them.